# javascript: Object Array looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I need to loop an javascript object array

This is my object `response`:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p3288namrojte20g\"",
 "summary": "pedicura",
 "updated": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z",
 "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Cordoba",
 "accessRole": "owner",
 "defaultReminders": [
  {
   "method": "popup",
   "minutes": 30
  }
 ],
 "nextSyncToken": "CJCLqtvE-uECEJCLqtvE-uECGAU=",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441344690000\"",
   "id": "hb6me2h********1dun5rs10",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=aGI2bWUyaGFvaGtqbWI4bXYxZHVuNXJzMTAgZTYyMXJtMD********Zw",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:12:08.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:24:32.345Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "pedicura",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-08T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-08T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "hb6me2ha----s10@google.com",
   "sequence": 2,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "aleja----it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "j----d@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441378884000\"",
   "id": "tv**0nbhkt**47la0k",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHZmOTQwbmJoa3Q3cnJvYjJsMW00N2xhMGsgZTYyMXJtM*****",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:18:53.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:24:49.442Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "pedicura",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-07T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-07T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "tvf940nbhk----m47la0k@google.com",
   "sequence": 2,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "ale---it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "j--d@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441503284000\"",
   "id": "tqhje1kd*****0",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHFoamUxa2Q0MG51M2Q3cGd2b2xlOGRqODAgZTYyMX*****",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "prueba",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-26T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-26T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "tqh*****7pgvole8dj80@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "-it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "-aud@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

and i want to do something like this:

```
var dataStr = JSON.stringify(response);
var dataPrs = JSON.parse(dataStr);
var dataList = JSON.stringify(dataPrs.items);
dataStr = JSON.stringify(dataList);
dataPrs = JSON.parse(dataStr);
dataListPrs.forEach( console.log(dataPrs.htmlLink) );
```

Comment: this current code shows this error ```SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data``` on this line ```dataPrs = JSON.parse(dataStr); ```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to do `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` everytime.

You need `JSON.stringify` only if you want to convert Javascript object into JSON string

and `JSON.parse` only if you want to convert JSON string to Javascript object and want to access its values with the key.

So, All you need is:

```js
const data = {
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p3288namrojte20g\"",
 "summary": "pedicura",
 "updated": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z",
 "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Cordoba",
 "accessRole": "owner",
 "defaultReminders": [
  {
   "method": "popup",
   "minutes": 30
  }
 ],
 "nextSyncToken": "CJCLqtvE-uECEJCLqtvE-uECGAU=",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441344690000\"",
   "id": "hb6me2h********1dun5rs10",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=aGI2bWUyaGFvaGtqbWI4bXYxZHVuNXJzMTAgZTYyMXJtMD********Zw",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:12:08.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:24:32.345Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "pedicura",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-08T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-08T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "hb6me2ha----s10@google.com",
   "sequence": 2,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "aleja----it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "j----d@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441378884000\"",
   "id": "tv**0nbhkt**47la0k",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHZmOTQwbmJoa3Q3cnJvYjJsMW00N2xhMGsgZTYyMXJtM*****",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:18:53.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:24:49.442Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "pedicura",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-07T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-07T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "tvf940nbhk----m47la0k@google.com",
   "sequence": 2,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "ale---it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "j--d@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441503284000\"",
   "id": "tqhje1kd*****0",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHFoamUxa2Q0MG51M2Q3cGd2b2xlOGRqODAgZTYyMX*****",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "prueba",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-26T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-26T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "tqh*****7pgvole8dj80@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "-it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "-aud@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  }
 ]
}

const items = data.items

items.forEach(x => console.log(x.htmlLink))
```

Comment: i still can't, this is what i've tryed:
```
console.log("Response", response);
var dataStr = JSON.stringify(response);
var dataPrs = JSON.parse(dataStr);
console.log("pse", dataPrs);
var body = dataPrs.body;
console.log("body", body);
    
console.log("items", body.items);
body.items.forEach(x => console.log(x.htmlLink));
```
but body.items is undefined

Comment: Why are you doing this: `var dataStr = JSON.stringify(response); var dataPrs = JSON.parse(dataStr);` stringify and parse again and again.